# jquery display fancybox when cookie has expired

Tags: jquery, cookies, fancybox

I need the fancybox to display when the cookie has expired, but this does not work? Can anyone help me?

```
var timer = 1;
$.cookie('popuptimer', 'timer', { expires: 2 * 60 * 1000 });

if($.cookie("popuptimer") == true){
} else {
   $.fancybox({
      overlayOpacity: 0.8,
      overlayColor: '#000',
      type: 'iframe',
      width: 625,
      height: 550,
      overflow: 'auto',
      padding: 0,
      href: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>feedback'
   });
}
```

Comment: you should run an Interval to check if the cookie expired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works even if the user goes to another page (this script has to be on every page).

```
function showPopuptimer(){
           $.fancybox({
              overlayOpacity: 0.8,
              overlayColor: '#000',
              type: 'iframe',
              width: 625,
              height: 550,
              overflow: 'auto',
              padding: 0,
              href: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>feedback'
           });
    }

if(!$.cookie("popuptimer") && $.cookie("olduser")){
    //Cookie has expired since the last visit
    showPopuptimer();
}else if($.cookie("popuptimer") && $.cookie("olduser")){
    //Wait for the cookie to expire, then show the box
    setTimeout(showPopuptimer,$.cookie("popuptimer"));
}else{
    $.cookie("olduser",true);
    $.cookie('popuptimer', 'timer', { expires: 2 * 60 * 1000 });
    setTimeout(showPopuptimer,2 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I need the popup to appear as soon as the cookie has expired, will I need to use ajax for this?

Comment: Ah yes I know, I would have but they will be going to different pages in the same website...that is my issue :(

Comment: I did something very similar to this and got it working - didn't use setTimeout though and now it works - thanks!

Comment: Timeout is use to show popup if the cookie expire without waiting for another page load :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for sth like:

```
http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/
```

Check the demo and thread , you will get an alternate idea hopefully